# Can't reset the values of upload_max_filesize and post_max_size using htaccess file

Tags: php, html

I've written  a php script for uploading file to my website. But it shows some error messages when the file size exceeds 8MB. It came to know that `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` are `8M` and `4M`. I haven't any access to the `php.ini` file where I hosted my site. I have tried to change the value of these variable using `ini_set()` and also created an htaccess file for doing the same when the first method became a big flop. This is the code in the htaccess file.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 100M
php_value max_execution_time 800
php_value post_max_size 100M
php_value max_input_time 100
php_value memory_limit 120M
```

Any solution to fix this issue?

Comment: Which SAPI invokes your php script? (`phpinfo()` tells you.) And please add the code of your .htaccess file.

Comment: You need to restart the apache server after changing the configuration , to take it into effect .. Try restarting apache ...

Comment: @AkhilThayyil Please, tell me you are not serious. The OP doesn't have access to `php.ini` how can he restart the apache daemon?

Comment: Be sure that you have at least the permission `AllowOverride Options` for that directory, otherwise the setting of `php_value` will not work

Comment: usually servers like of godaddy restarts every day 12 am , also u can do process restart from their cpanel after changing modifications to php.ini

Comment: usually Apache doesn't need to be restarted to apply changes in .htaccess-files

Comment: Also for godaddy hosting there we can create php.ini accourding to the version of php we needed ... ,

Comment: @Dr.Molle, How and where can I set this AllowOverride

Comment: You cannot set it if you don't have access to the server-configuration(httpd.conf or vhosts.conf ). Also ini_set() will not work, because these options are changeable only for PHP_INI_PERDIR, what means you cannot change it from within a script.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't written which SAPI you're using, so this might not always work:

http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php

You must have PHP configured as Apache module to make your configuration work.

Double check the documentation if this applies for your use-case and double check your server configuration.

Additionally I don't know if writing 120M is correct here or you need to write the number of bytes as a number only.

Next to that there is an alternative approach with ini files per directory, see

http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php

This might be a workaround for your case.